# Android - onTabChanged not being invoked upon selecting a different tab

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Thanks for checking out my inquiry!

I have implemented a tab environment as illustrated below. It seems to work as I expected except that it never executes the onTabChanged method. I have found several posts about this type of situation but have not been able to get my code to work the way I expected. Advice?

Thanks,
Chip

```
public class TestTabActivity extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Page1Activity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("page1").setIndicator("Page 1",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_page1))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Page2Activity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("page2").setIndicator("Page 2",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_page2))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Page2Activity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("page3").setIndicator("Page 3",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_page3))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}   

public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    Log.d("Tab Changed", "Changed a Tab");
}
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't see that you register your class for a tab change with `tabHost.`[setOnTabChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setOnTabChangedListener%28android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener%29)`(this)`.

I would suggest to do that before `tabHost.setCurrentTab(0)`.

Even if it's not called on the first set of the tab you can manually call `onTabChanged("page1")` at the end of `onCreate`.

Or did I missunderstood your problem?

Comment: Thank you Knickedi! I was blind but now I see.